# makefile: pass variable number of arguments

Tags: makefile, pytest

I have a Makefile like so:

```
test:
     pytest $(args)

.PHONY: test
```

My goal is to be able to call tests, like `make test -v -k "test_foo"`, or `make test -m`

How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the arguments to the Makefile target as:

```sh
make args="-v -s" test
```